# How to print a python variable with a html content as a 'page' in terminal?

Tags: python, html, terminal

I have python variable with a html content like

> `>>>>a='<html><h1><a href="http://www.google.com">Link to Google<></h1></html>'`

How can I print it as a html?

I would like print this variable in my terminal and I would like a result like this:

[image: a.html]

OBS.: If python can do this without shell script or other programs I will prefer this.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python

Comment: @WayneWerner it's very interesting. But unfortunally the variables that I want to print is already in html. I don't need the colors truly, it's interesting, but I'm interested on interpret html in python and print it like a webpage.

See this example pastebin [link](http://pastebin.com/PJF58pX1):

Comment: I'm still confused at what you want - you told martincho that you did not want plain text, you wanted the formatting of the links to show up. However, in your example image there is only plain text colored blue. Now you tell me that you don't need colors? Are you just trying to display the text of the page, or do you want to be able to interact with it in some way?

Comment: This color text is just the way how the w3m interpret html if I open this same file in a brownser they will look like a "normal" webpage.

Comment: So the question is: what exactly do you want to display? Do you want to create a Python-only version of w3m? Do you just want to display the text on the webpage?

Comment: I would like print html contents and display (in terminal) it like webpages not just a simple text. This is a interesting, or important thing if you are using crawlers. Treat all htmls tags can be anoying,or impossible but if python interprets it everything can become more easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had success doing a python program **a.py** as below:

```
a='<html><h1>My example text</h1></html>'
file=open("a.html","w")
file.write(a+'\n')
file.close
```

and then doing another shell script **a.sh** something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/env python a.py
w3m a.html
```

But I think it isn't a good way, isn't there one that only uses python?

Answer (score 1):

I hope someone can give you a better answer, but I'm going to tell you my idea anyway: you can use html2text -I think it's a Python script- or, html2pdf and then pdf2text. And finally print the generated text of course. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hum...I would like print the content of the variable with the web/html formats or highlights...for example blue to links and other things. I wouldn't like change to plain text...

Comment: I edited the question. I think it's more precise now. See my print. Thx for help.

Answer (score 1):

to trim the tags from the above example I used:

```
    >>> a='<html><\p>My example text<p></html>'
    >>> while '<' in a or '>' in a:
    ...     a = a.replace(a[a.find('<'):a.find('>')+1],"")
    ... 
    >>> a
    'My example text'
```

That should work unless the text you want to extract contains '<' or '>', or if the variable is invalid html.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Hum...but I don't want change the html, I would like to keep it, but show it as a html. Until know I had printed the variable to a file and then called this file if the `w3m`, but maybe there's a better solution.

Comment: @colton7909 I edited the question. I think it's more precise now. See my print. Thx for help.

Comment: Oh my apologies. That is a much bigger question than I originally thought. I'm not sure I can help you with that, but I did find this (http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html) library in the documentation